# Java: Boolean outputs false but should output true

Tags: java, boolean

I tried to make this boolean in java work, but it doesn't work for no obvious reason:

`c.charAt(0) -> 1`
`c.charAt(0)==1` -> false ???

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
String c = "111";
System.out.println(c.charAt(0)==1);
}}
```

Output:
`false`

The output should be `true`, because `1==1` is `true`.
I don't understand what happens here or how to fix it.

Do I need to change the 1 in that boolean to something else? Or define the boolean outside of the brackets?

Thank you for your help ^^

Comment: `1` and `'1'` are different things, read about chars in java :)

Comment: `'1'` is a `char` with an [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of `49`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the type, 1 is type int while c.charAt(0) is type char, you should compare like this

```
c.charAt(0) == '1'
```

Comment: Alternatively: `c.startsWith("1")`.

Comment: Andy's version is better because it doesn't cause a problem if you call it on an empty string.